# how to share files with Share Provider in android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to share image on share button click, but in my code not working properly,

```
shareBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(mImagePath);
            
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/jpeg");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
        });
```

in my app, I fetching images from gallery, showing in app while sharing image this code working,

How should I share image from my app to another?

Comment: What is `Share Provider`? And where are you using it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/ShareActionProvider

Comment: Interesting. But you should show more complete code as we do not know type and value of mImagePath. Further what is 'not working properly'?